# Event triggering and sending messages to a server according to those events from a client in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-multithreading

suppose we run a server in localhost on the port 6000 (say server A). We have our own client which communicates with this server (sends messages to the server A). Server A sends messages from time to time to another server runs on port 7000 (say server B) which is also in our control. Our client should send messages to server according to certain messages received by server B.

This is a set of example steps of what I want to achieve

1. OurClient send message (JOIN) to ServerA
2. ServerA send message (ACKNOWLEDGED) to ServerB
3. ServerA send message (PATH_CLEAR) to ServerB
4. ServerB inform (PATH_CLEAR) to OurClient
5. OurClient send message (MOVE_FORWARD) to ServerA
6. ServerA send message (MOVED_FORWARD_BY_A_CELL) to ServerB
7. ServerA send message (OBSTACLE_AHEAD) to ServerB
8. ServerB inform (OBSTACLE_AHEAD) to OurClient
9. OurClient send message (STOP) to ServerA
10. ServerA  send message (STOPPED) to ServerB
    ......
    ....

I have used socket module in Python to connect to the server and to create our client and server. Should I use threads to achieve such behavior? If so how do I do that?

I tried to do so 
here's the code I've used for that
[How to trigger to responses from a server using python socket programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501007/how-to-trigger-to-responses-from-a-server-using-python-socket-programming)

but once the other server accepts my '#JOIN' message I can't send messages anymore. My client doesn't send messages after that first message. How do I fix this?

Is there any alternative method of how I could do this or are there any changes I should do to my code?

Comment: Probably you should use a high-level RPC library like xmlrpc, [RPyC](http://rpyc.sourceforge.net/index.html) or [Pyro](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyro4). Otherwise you have to show us your code...

Comment: If you don't show any code it is difficult to understand what you are doing wrong. In general on sockets it is quite possible to send several messages on the same socket.

Comment: My code is shown in the link in the above question. If I restate it : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501007/how-to-trigger-to-responses-from-a-server-using-python-socket-programming

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use multithreading, you can just use the module "select", and i suggest using the method poll, to know which file descriptors are ready to be used.

In general using select or poll is faster than using threads.